# Integrate gedmo/doctrine extension with Codeigniter

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, codeigniter-3

I have integrated doctrine orm in my newly created project with CodeIgniter 3.0 project with this [repo](https://github.com/rubensarrio/codeigniter-hmvc-doctrine) and other sites.

Now, I want to use doctrine extension, gedmo and its not working but also no error but when I try to create a row on database, it says created_at cannot be null which has Gedmo/Timestampable to get current date time.

Here is my `Doctrine.php` file

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

use Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader,
    Doctrine\ORM\Configuration,
    Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
    Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache,
    Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader,
    Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver,
    Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger,
    Doctrine\Common\EventManager;

use Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener,
    Gedmo\Sluggable\SluggableListener;

class Doctrine {

public $em = null;

public function __construct()
{
    // load database configuration from CodeIgniter
    require_once APPPATH.'config/database.php';


    //A Doctrine Autoloader is needed to load the models
    // first argument of classloader is namespace and second argument is path
    // setup models/entity namespace
    $entityLoader = new ClassLoader('models', APPPATH);
    $entityLoader->register();

    foreach (glob(APPPATH.'modules/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $m) {
        $module = str_replace(APPPATH.'modules/', '', $m);
        $entityLoader = new ClassLoader($module, APPPATH.'modules');
        $entityLoader->register();
    }
    //Register proxies namespace
    $proxyLoader = new ClassLoader('Proxies', APPPATH.'Proxies');
    $proxyLoader->register();


    // Set up caches
    $config = new Configuration;
    $cache = new ArrayCache;
    $config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
    $driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(array(APPPATH.'models'));
    $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
    $config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);

    // Set up entity
    $reader = new AnnotationReader($cache);
    $models = array(APPPATH.'models');
    foreach (glob(APPPATH.'modules/*/models', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $m)
        array_push($models, $m);
    $driver = new AnnotationDriver($reader, $models);
    $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);

    // Setup Gedmo
    $cachedAnnotationReader = new Doctrine\Common\Annotations\CachedReader(
        $reader, // use reader
        $cache // and a cache driver
    );

    // create a driver chain for metadata reading
    $driverChain = new Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DriverChain();

    // load superclass metadata mapping only, into driver chain
    // also registers Gedmo annotations.NOTE: you can personalize it
    Gedmo\DoctrineExtensions::registerAbstractMappingIntoDriverChainORM(
        $driverChain, // our metadata driver chain, to hook into
        $cachedAnnotationReader // our cached annotation reader
    );

    $event = new EventManager;

    $timestampableListener = new TimestampableListener;
    $timestampableListener->setAnnotationReader($cachedAnnotationReader);
    $event->addEventSubscriber($timestampableListener);

    $slugListener = new SluggableListener;
    $slugListener->setAnnotationReader($cachedAnnotationReader);
    $event->addEventSubscriber($slugListener);


    // Proxy configuration
    $config->setProxyDir(APPPATH.'/proxies');
    $config->setProxyNamespace('Proxies');

    // Set up logger
    // $logger = new EchoSQLLogger;
    // $config->setSQLLogger($logger);

    $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses( TRUE );

    // Database connection information
    $connectionOptions = array(
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
        'user' =>     $db['default']['username'],
        'password' => $db['default']['password'],
        'host' =>     $db['default']['hostname'],
        'dbname' =>   $db['default']['database']
    );

    // Create EntityManager
    $this->em = EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);
}
```

}

Can anyone tell, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

you need to call Gedmo I think!

```
        // Set up models loading
    $loader = new ClassLoader('models', APPPATH);
    $loader->register();
    foreach (glob(APPPATH . 'modules/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $m) {
        $module = str_replace(APPPATH . 'modules/', '', $m);
        $loader = new ClassLoader($module, APPPATH . 'modules');
        $loader->register();
    }

    // Set up Gedmo
    $classLoader = new ClassLoader('Gedmo', APPPATH . 'third_party');
    $classLoader->register();
    $evm = new EventManager;
    // timestampable
    $evm->addEventSubscriber(new TimestampableListener);
    // sluggable
    $evm->addEventSubscriber(new SluggableListener);
    // tree
    $evm->addEventSubscriber(new TreeListener);

    // Set up proxies loading
    $loader = new ClassLoader('Proxies', APPPATH . 'Proxies');
    $loader->register();

    // Set up caches
    $config = new Configuration;
    $cache = new ArrayCache;
    $config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);

    // Set up models
    $models = array(APPPATH . 'models');
    foreach (glob(APPPATH . 'modules/*/models', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $m)
        array_push($models, $m);
    // Set up driver
    $driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver($models);
    $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
    $config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);


    // Proxy configuration
    $config->setProxyDir(APPPATH . 'Proxies'); //must be set to chmod 777
    $config->setProxyNamespace('Proxies');
```

Comment: Questions on SO should be complete. You should point out what the issue in the question is, and what has been done to resolve it. As it is posted, this answer doesn't appear to be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

i made up this solution for integrating Doctrine 2 + Codeigniter 3 HMVC + composer

I installed Doctrine using composer

```
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"require": {        
    "doctrine/orm": "2.4.*",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "2.4.*",
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "5.2.8"
}
```

Architecture

```
-application
    --config
    --...
    --libraries
    ---Doctrine.php
    --vendor
    --proxies (must be set to 777)
    --composer.json
```

then i called doctrine through autoload.php file $autoload['libraries'] = array('doctrine');

then create my Doctrine.php file like below :

```
use Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader,
    Doctrine\ORM\Configuration,
    Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
    Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache,
    Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger,
    Doctrine\DBAL\Event\Listeners\MysqlSessionInit,
    Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool,
    Doctrine\Common\EventManager,
    Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader,
    Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver,
    Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener,
    Gedmo\Sluggable\SluggableListener,
    Gedmo\Tree\TreeListener
    ;

class Doctrine {

public $em = null;
public $tool = null;

public function __construct()
{

    // Is the config file in the environment folder?
    if (!defined('ENVIRONMENT') OR !file_exists($file_path = APPPATH . 'config/' . ENVIRONMENT . '/database.php')) {
        $file_path = APPPATH.'config/database.php';
    }
    // load database configuration from CodeIgniter
    require $file_path;


    // Set up class loading. You could use different autoloaders, provided by your favorite framework,
    // if you want to.
    require_once APPPATH.'vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';

    $doctrineClassLoader = new ClassLoader('Doctrine',  APPPATH.'libraries');
    $doctrineClassLoader->register();
    $entitiesClassLoader = new ClassLoader('models', rtrim(APPPATH, "/" ));
    $entitiesClassLoader->register();
    $proxiesClassLoader = new ClassLoader('Proxies', APPPATH.'proxies');
    $proxiesClassLoader->register();


    foreach (glob(APPPATH . 'modules/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $m) {
        $module = str_replace(APPPATH . 'modules/', '', $m);
        $loader = new ClassLoader($module, APPPATH . 'modules');
        $loader->register();
    }


    $evm = new EventManager;
    // timestampable
    $evm->addEventSubscriber(new TimestampableListener);
    // sluggable
    $evm->addEventSubscriber(new SluggableListener);
    // tree
    $evm->addEventSubscriber(new TreeListener);


    // Set up caches
    $config = new Configuration;
    $cache = new ArrayCache;
    $config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
    $driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(array(APPPATH.'models/Entities'));
    $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
    $config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);

    $config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);

    // Proxy configuration
    $config->setProxyDir(APPPATH.'/proxies'); //must be set to 777
    $config->setProxyNamespace('Proxies');

    // Set up logger
    $logger = new EchoSQLLogger;
    $config->setSQLLogger($logger);



    if (ENVIRONMENT == "development") {
        $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses( TRUE );
    } else {
        $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses( FALSE );
    }


    // Database connection information
    $connectionOptions = array(
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
        'user' =>     $db[$active_group]['username'],
        'password' => $db[$active_group]['password'],
        'host' =>     $db[$active_group]['hostname'],
        'dbname' =>   $db[$active_group]['database']
    );

    // Create EntityManager
    $this->em = EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);


    // Force UTF-8
    $this->em->getEventManager()->addEventSubscriber( new MysqlSessionInit('utf8', 'utf8_unicode_ci'));

    // Schema Tool
    $this->tool = new SchemaTool($this->em);

}
}
```

and it works, hope this will help, :)